# No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I am writing code to upload files to AWS S3 and receiving this exception:

> AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

My code:

```
Console.WriteLine("ready to upload");
AWSCredentials credentials;
credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID.Trim(), secretKey.Trim());
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKeyID.Trim(), secretKey.Trim(), Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
Console.WriteLine("Successful verification");
Console.WriteLine("Check if the bucket exists");
if (!CheckBucketExists(s3Client, bucketName))
{
    s3Client.PutBucket(bucketName);
    Console.WriteLine("create bucket");
}
TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility();
Console.WriteLine("Upload  Directory......");
//exception here
utility.UploadDirectory(@"E:\telerikFile\13ginabdfglil.com", bucketName);
```

The exception:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured
  Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.Validate()
  Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config.Validate()
  Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient..ctor(AWSCredentials credentials, ClientConfig config)
  Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client..ctor()
  Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility..ctor()
  Telerik2Amazon.Program.UploadFile()
```

What should I do?

Comment: For services like S3 or EC2, specifying endpoint is must. So `new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1)` should work.

Comment: Setting the environment variable AWS_REGION will also work.

Answer (score 50):

The short answer to error...

> Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

...in my case was to specify a region when constructing the client object (for me it was `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient`).

Assuming you're using `BasicAWSCredentials` then try this:

```
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID, secretKey);

new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  add this
```

Answer (score 15):

First of all, you shouldn't hardcode aws credentials.

I had a similar error.  Turned out it was due to changes in .Net Core:

> One of the biggest changes in .NET Core is the removal of ConfigurationManager and the standard app.config and web.config files
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html

For quick and dirty approach you can create credintial profile file on your machine see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html

e.g. `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.aws\credentials` on Windows

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = your_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key = your_secret_access_key
```

then in your code you can just do something like:

```
var dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new StoredProfileAWSCredentials(), 
                     RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

A more involved way is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html#net-core-configuration-builder

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

`appsettings.Development.json`

```
{
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "local-test-profile",
    "Region": "us-west-2"
  }
}


var options = Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
IAmazonS3 client = options.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonS3>();
```

Comment: Still should avoid hard code the region.. because if you move it to Europe or Asia.. you will be connecting to the wrong stuff. On AWS it just uses the roles access and regions of the executing code. THe profiles are really there to "override" this if needed.. but that is rarely the case - use the "more involved way" which is really the more preffered way.. and not that difficult

Comment: The issue I found with this is that I needed to use the DryRun() method from AmazonEC2Client, which is not available with IAmazonEC2. If I try to use the CreateServiceClient<T>() with AmazonEC2Client, it fails to create the client, throwing a "Object not set to a reference" error :(

Answer (score 14):

I received this error when running tests for a Lambda that uses the S3 client. I resolved the error by simply providing a default profile with a region defined in `~/.aws/config`:

```
[default]
region = us-west-1
```

No Lambda code changes needed. Of course YMMV depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

In Asp.Net this error can be fixed by adding this line to Web.config:

```
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1" />
```

Worked for me for AWSSDK.SimpleEmail v3.3

Comment: Use `/.aws/credentials` file instead. It can be easily created using `Visual Studio AWS Toolkit`. This makes sense because when you deploy then the EC2/Lambda instance uses the roles "metadata" and gets all the info it needs. Sorry -1 cause people then copy and paste this not understanding how AWS credentials work (eg, myself)

Answer (score 5):

My access key id and secret key are can be used.
Therefore I give up using TransferUtility Class and chosing another  Class named PutObjectRequest to upload my files
**attontion**:
  PutObjectRequest’s Property **Key**,it's directory name and file name must equal to **local files**'  directory name and file name.
**codes here:**

```
        String s3Path = "987977/Baby.db";
        Console.WriteLine("Ready to upload");
        AWSCredentials credentials;
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID.Trim(), secretKey.Trim());
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKeyID.Trim(), secretKey.Trim(), Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        Console.WriteLine("Successful verification");
        Console.WriteLine("Check： if the bucket exists");
        if (!CheckBucketExists(s3Client, bucketName))
        {
            s3Client.PutBucket(bucketName);
            Console.WriteLine("Creat bucket");
        }
        string localPath = @"E:\telerikFile\987977\Baby.db";
        PutObjectRequest obj = new PutObjectRequest();
        var fileStream = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  //      obj.FilePath= @"E:\telerikFile\987977\Baby.db";
        obj.InputStream = fileStream;
        obj.BucketName = bucketName;
        obj.Key = s3Path;
       // obj.ContentBody = "This is sample content...";
        obj.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
        Console.WriteLine("uploading");
        // default to set public right  
        s3Client.PutObject(obj);
```

Comment: For some reason, even using this approach was giving me the same error until I added on the file C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.aws\credentials the default profile.
I actually don't use the credentials on that file, but if it is missing it throws the error. It seems that it requires you the default profile on that file no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `TransferUtility()` try this:

```
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID, secretKey);

var S3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

this._transferUtility = new TransferUtility(S3Client);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET Core, there's no longer a `web.config` or `app.config`, instead the ConfigurationBuilder is used, which can retrieve configuration from a number of different sources.

The web templates for .NET use `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` which relies on environment variables and the `appsettings.json` file, for other applications the following can be done:

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(APPSETTINGS, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```

This will retrieve configuration from the `appsettings.json` file, but also from environment variables, and allows you to retrieve them as follows:

```
var region = configuration["AWS_REGION"];
```

The AWS SDK will use this configuration to retrieve the region for services retreived through Dependency Injection in any ASP.NET Core application. For Lambda's you'll need to construct a ServiceCollection manually for that to work, which can be done as such.

```
private readonly ServiceProvider serviceProvider;

public Function()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAmazonDynamoDB, AmazonDynamoDBClient>();
    serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}

public void FunctionHandler(string input, LambdaContext context)
{
    var dynamodb = serviceProvider.GetService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
    // Business logic here
}
```

This approach should be sufficient for pretty much every use-case. If you're having issues with this, please try to troubleshoot that rather than attempt the fall-back below.

**This next bit is only here for completeness, but you really shouldn't need it.**

When using the above fails, you can fall back on the `AWSConfigs` static to set your environment variables explicitly. Using the below approach allows us to reuse our existing configuration, whether that is in the `appsettings.json` or in the Environment variables.

```
AWSConfigs.AWSRegion = configuration["AWS_REGION"];
```

Comment: Thanks, `AWSConfigs.AWSRegion = configuration["ap-southeast-2"];` was all I needed to get mocks and unit tests working on our Code Pipeline build server.

Comment: @thinkOfaNumber be very weary of using this in unit tests, especially if you are running your tests in parallel, as we were. Because this static field is shared across threads, setting this in one place will set it everywhere and may lead to your tests becoming non-deterministic.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem if all unit tests are using the same region, right? I'm not testing changing the region, just trying to mock out the AmazonIotDataClient so I can test my services without actually calling PublishAsync.

Comment: Right, that should work fine. We were having tests that tested the validity of the region as well, which required some of them to have different values set, thus causing problems.

Comment: You can use the Nuget: AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup and then wire up your AWS service like so:
```
services.TryAddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>(configuration.GetAWSOptions("sqs"));
```
This assumes you've got your appsettings.json with a section like so:
```
{
"sqs": {
    "ServiceURL": "https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had this error trying to run [this sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-qldb-dmv-sample-dotnet) code that creates some lambda functions to interact with AWS QLDB.
I had to only follow one of the options from [this post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html), which in my case was:

- [Managing access keys for IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey)
- Configure your project, by [Using the shared AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-file.html), adding this settings to
  %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials file

credentials file:

```
[default] 
region = your_region_id
aws_access_key_id = your_aws_access_key_id 
aws_secret_access_key = your_aws_secret_access_key
```

But you could use any of the different ways AWS SDK finds the credentials, checking [Credential and profile resolution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-assign.html)

Answer (score -3):

I also have this issue and nothing was helpful, aws is the worst, so complicated and their documentation is subpar that of microsft's no wonder Azure is taking marketshare

Comment: This should probably have been a comment rather than an answer.