# Getting Error(No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured) on EC2 instance even if IAM roles are setup in .net web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've configured IAM roles for my different services on EC2 server.with the help of below link  [IAM Role Setup](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2-instances-access-key-management-for-net-applications-part-4/). According to AWS docs after setting IAM role we don't need any credentials to be stored in our application it takes the credential details from EC2 instance metadata.
However, I am getting error when I removed AWS key from my  web.config.**"No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured"** After some time when I added region point entry to my Web.config  entry then it started working.

```
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1" />
```

Please note in another application where I am accessing only AWS DynamoDB on the same server, it works without adding region point entry in config. Any kind of help is appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: What service and what SDK?

Comment: Latest version AWSSDK  is installed.

Comment: Solution tried here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055665/no-regionendpoint-or-serviceurl-configured

Answer (score 2):

**IAM role is only for fetching credentials** from the metadata server, **not for the region** you are trying to connect to. So, you have to specify the region in the config file, not the credentials. Some services default to a region (like `us-east-1`) but many services expect the region to be configured or passed when creating a client object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. will you Please share a link to AWS docs mentioning the same